# How should I reload tableview content after switching containers.

Tags: caching, switch-statement, tableview, containers, reload

I have a container view that can be switched between a tableview and a mapview when a user presses a UIButton.   det determines which container view it is currently in.

```
- (IBAction)changer:(id)sender{

if(det == TRUE){
  TableViewController *viewController2 = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
viewController2.view.frame = self.container.bounds;

[viewController2 willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.container addSubview:viewController2.view];
[self addChildViewController:viewController2];
[viewController2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft  forView:self.container cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];



    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 35)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapSwitch.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:back];

    det = FALSE;
}
else{

    ViewController *viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc1"];
    viewController1.view.frame = self.container.bounds;

    [viewController1 willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.container addSubview:viewController1.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController1];
    [viewController1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight  forView:self.container cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];



    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 35)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listSwitch.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:back];

    det = TRUE;

}
```

}

The switching is just fine; it loads the tableview first which is populated correctly. Then, if you switch to the mapview, it is also fine. However, when I switch back to the table view and call a

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

method, the tableview is empty. Basically I have 2 arrays of info that need to be displayed on the tableview which return the correct information/content after switching back to the tableview, but do not appear in the tableview after reloaddata.

Is reloadData is not the best way to reload a tableview that was created before? I suspect that when the changer method reloads the tableview container, something is happening so there is nothing in the table view.

Or is there a way to "cache" the tableview so when you switch back to it, everything stays rather than reloading everything again?